# Source Code Needed to Recover Corrupt Word 2010 .docx

Tags: password-protection

I have a corrupted, password-protected Office 2010 Word Document, with .docx extension, it has file links inside,and is about 1000 pages long.

I want to save any data that I can.  I have tried many different things..

Any ideas on Programs or Source Code to do this?

Comment: Your question is very well hidden among all the story-telling. I think you should cut it down to the essence if you expect people to read it. After all, you can still provide more information afterwards by editing your question.

Comment: blubb thanks for your comment.  I have shortened it.

Answer (score 0):

docx are zip files with a number of entries inside.  Step 1 would be try to open the docx in a zip file viewer such as WinZip or 7-zip.

If the ZIP is corrupted, you could try to repair it, though because your docx document is password protected, recovery if one or more entry in the zip file is lost may be difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Rename it to .ZIP and then use a repair tool to browse the contents which are a mix of XML and binary files in a specific structure.

See [Structure of the Office XML Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx#office2007aboutnewfileformat_structureoftheofficexmlformats) for what is contained in the .zip /.docx file.